# How can I match size information in an AdWords query?

Tags: google-ads

I want to create keywords containing a size. 
eg.

- rugs 90 x 60
- rugs 180 x 120
- rugs 400 x 300

It seems this is possible as Amazon actually shows ads like this for such a query. They also insert it into the headline, body and URL. How can I do that?

If I just create lots of keywords I can obviously not easily target every possible size. I am also afraid it is not so easy to have the ad not blocked for low impressions.

UPDATE: I found out Amazon just has a list of very many popular sizes and ads will not trigger on odd queries like "rugs 91 x 53". This data can theoretically be captured on the server side to show a better landing page by using the query field in the referrer.

It seems adwords is completely text based and nothing akin to Regexp is possible at all. One can also not mix exact and broad match keywords in one query to help write less ads.

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? I don't undersatnd it.